# Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I get this error when I compile to production.

> Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding".

The compiler worked fine until now, only today when I backed up a styles.css.scss file this error occurred.

In production env I have

```
  config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb', '*.scss']
```

content of styles.css.scss

```
$btn-default-bg: green;
$btn-default-color: white;
$navbar-default-bg: white;
$navbar-default-border: white;
@import 'bootstrap';

html{

height:100%;  

}

body {
  height:100%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  background: rgba(0,123,91,1);
}

// @import 'bootstrap-responsive';
.navbar-header,
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1{
  background: #004835 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
  color:#ffffff;
}

nav{
  border:none !important;
}
```

application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require phrasing
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Comment: did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Also having the same issue. Did you fix it?

Comment: It's a duplicate, It was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911620/rails-bootstrap-sass-assets-compilation-error-undefined-variable-alert-padding In other words, just comment the assets.precompile line in your application.rb or production.rb file.