# Undefined variable: "$alert-padding" using Rails, AngularJS and Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, sass

I am experiencing an issue while precompiling the assets of my Rails projects.

Here is the versions of some of the gems I am using:

```
rails (4.2.0)
bootstrap-sass (3.3.3)
sass-rails (5.0.1)
```

The project is an AngularJS project sourcing the following gems from [Rails Asset](http://rails-assets.org):

```
rails-assets-bootstrap-additions (0.2.3)
rails-assets-angular-bootstrap (0.11.2)
rails-assets-bootstrap-sass-official (3.3.3)
```

Following the [README on the bootstrap-sass Github page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass), I renamed my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file to `application.scss` and replaced its content by:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Here is the error I get when I launch `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace`:

```
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding".
   (in /home/owner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_alerts.scss:10)
```

I looked into ClothSword's answer to [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21935120/378253), but in my case `puts config.assets.precompile.inspect` outputs `(lambda)>, /(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$/]`, which I believe to be the default.

Would anyone have more insight on this? You can browse the source [here](https://bitbucket.org/fuzzybird/tealure-spree/src)

Comment: Unless you're modifying the contents of your Bootstrap gem, this looks like either a versioning problem (you'll likely need to switch to Sass 3.3 or older... *or* 3.4, depending on which one will make the error go away) or an error in Bootstrap itself.

Comment: what does your main scss file look like?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem I'm facing is that one of the gem I'm using, `sprangular`, is setting this precompile rule:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap/* )
```

If I comment out this rule and source my own modified version of the gem in the Gemfile, `rake assets:precompile` now works.

I'm not entirely sure the reason why they set a rule to precompile all of the boostrap files. Does that make sense?

I've created [an issue in their Github repo](https://github.com/sprangular/sprangular/issues/95) to gain clarity on whether this is a bug or just me not configuring the asset pipeline properly in my app.

I will update this answer as I get clarity from the discussion over there. Feel free to make suggestions here too.